# How to set the default GPG encryption key?

Tags: gnupg, gpgpu, gpg4win, gpg-agent

Say I am using only one encryption key most the time.

**How do I set the default encryption key in order to avoid mentioning it in the encryption command**

In other word, I want this command:

```
gpg -e
```

to be equivalent to the command with the recipient

```
gpg -e -r reciever@mail.edu
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GnuPG knows the `--default-recipient` option, which does exactly what you're looking for.

```
--default-recipient name
      Use name as default recipient if option --recipient is not used and don't
      ask if this is a valid one. name must be non-empty.
```

You can specify all GnuPG options in your GnuPG configuration file `gpg.conf` by omitting the `--` prefix, for example

```
default-recipient reciever@mail.edu
```

Comment: "... and don't ask if this is a valid one" is a confusing wording... at least in my opinion.

Comment: @Ini you're not alone in your opinion; it sounds like an imperative clause. My guess at what it means is "the given `name` is not validated like many of the other options that take names."